# How to add custom customer attribute only for adminhtml in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I am using below code for adding customer attribute in admin form with some required value.

```
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_name",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Company Name",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"  => false,
        "note"    => ""

    ));
    $company_name   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_name");

    $company_name = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'company_name');
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $company_name->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $company_name->save();


    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_registration",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Company Registration",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));
    $company_registration   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_registration");

    $company_registration = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,'company_registration');
    $used_in_forms  = array(); 
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $company_registration->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 110);
    $company_registration->save();


    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "gst_no",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Gst No.",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));
    $gst_no   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "gst_no");

    $gst_no = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,'gst_no');
    $used_in_forms  = array(); 
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $gst_no->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 110);
    $gst_no->save();


      $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_address",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Company Address",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));
    $company_address   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_address");

    $company_address = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,'company_address');
    $used_in_forms  = array(); 
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $company_address->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 110);
    $company_address->save();



      $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "contact_number",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Company Number",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));
    $contact_number   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "contact_number");

    $contact_number = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,'contact_number');
    $used_in_forms  = array(); 
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $contact_number->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 110);
    $contact_number->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
```

But It gives me error of required values in registration form. I don't want these fields in registration forms.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use setvisible to 0

```
->setData("is_visible", 0)
```

Try this

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "facebook",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Facebook",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "facebook");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 0)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Can you please let me know what is diffrence between this script ?

Comment: i have updated my answer.please mark correct to my answer  if it is useful for you.thanks